# I can't break out of C# solution.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 C# that uses the timer and sends a message box out to the user at every tick with the time (I don't why I did that just testing I guess). The issue is that I can't seem to find a way to stop the program...I just keep getting the message box coming every tick. I've used taskmanager to kill the process but as soon as I open the solution the message boxes come back. No matter what I've tried I can't stop the execution of the program. It's a laptop, and I've tried ctl-break ctl-fn-break. Nothing seems to work. If anyone has a suggestion for this issue, I would appreciate it. There must be a way to stop the program. Thanks.

Comment: When you used Task Manager, did the process go away?

Comment: I built the solution. In the solution there is a user control with a timer that fires a message of the time each second. When I kill the process with taskmanager it ends but as soon as I open up the solution the message box starts firing. I think its because the user control is independant that I can't stop it. Looks like I'll have to build a new project.

Comment: Comment out MessageBox.Show().  Could the designer be running the timer and issuing the message boxes?  That would be news to me.

Comment: @MatthewSomers - The usercontrol would run in the context of the process it is owned by. Are you stopping your process or the Visual Studio process? Either way, is the *.vshost.exe process dieing too?

Comment: That's the thing. I can't. As soon as I open the program, the message box starts.

Comment: Edit the file in notepad, then reopen VS.

Comment: +1 for one of the most curious ways to twit yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that when Visual Studio opens the solution it is immediately opening the forms designer and rendering the offending form, thus the never-ending message box.

Edit the class file with the message box code in notepad (I believe the designer dynamically compiles files in the background as you work). Delete any assemblies related to the solution to be on the safe side. If that doesn't work, copy the form's code to a text file, and delete and recreate.

Comment: If this is actually coming from the designer I would love to see the code.

Comment: @roken - the designer will execute whatever it can for web or windows forms. One of my developers encountered this problem recently where an infinite loop in a custom control crashed VS every time it launched. That's one of the reasons the `DesignMode` property exists, so you can conditionally omit things which should not execute in the designer.

Comment: Ahh yes, I suppose.  Note that use of DesignMode in the UserControl to suppress the timer enablement would be insufficent, because DesignMode is only true when that control is being designed.  If you drop the usercontrol on a From, DesignMode will not help you when designing the form.

Comment: @roken: any code in the default constructor will be run if you bring up the designer.

Comment: @InBetween - not for the control you are designing. the key is that this timer is coming from a usercontrol dropped on a form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code that is starting the timer and wrap it in. But you'll have to open the .cs file specifically.

```
if(!this.DesignMode)
{
     //enter timer code here
}
```